# TF-IDF vectorizer to extract ngrams

Tags: python, scikit-learn, n-gram, tfidfvectorizer

How can I use `TF-IDF vectorizer` from the scikit-learn library to extract `unigrams` and `bigrams` of tweets? I want to train a classifier with the output.

This is the code from scikit-learn:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
corpus = [
    'This is the first document.',
    'This document is the second document.',
    'And this is the third one.',
    'Is this the first document?',
]
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TfidfVectorizer` has an `ngram_range` parameter to determin the range of n-grams you want in the final matrix as new features. In your case, you want `(1,2)` to go from unigrams to bigrams:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2))
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus).todense()

pd.DataFrame(X, columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names())

        and  and this  document  document is     first  first document  \
0  0.000000  0.000000  0.314532     0.000000  0.388510        0.388510   
1  0.000000  0.000000  0.455513     0.356824  0.000000        0.000000   
2  0.357007  0.357007  0.000000     0.000000  0.000000        0.000000   
3  0.000000  0.000000  0.282940     0.000000  0.349487        0.349487   

         is    is the   is this       one  ...       the  the first  \
0  0.257151  0.314532  0.000000  0.000000  ...  0.257151   0.388510   
1  0.186206  0.227756  0.000000  0.000000  ...  0.186206   0.000000   
2  0.186301  0.227873  0.000000  0.357007  ...  0.186301   0.000000   
3  0.231322  0.000000  0.443279  0.000000  ...  0.231322   0.349487   
...
```

Comment: Can I change ngrams from words to characters?

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html

you specify n-grams when initializing TfidfVectorizer, `TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range(min_n, max_n))`
The lower and upper boundary of the range of n-values for different n-grams to be extracted
`ngram_range` of `(1, 1)` means only `unigrams`, `(1, 2)` means `unigrams` and `bigrams`, and `(2, 2)` means only `bigrams`.

Answer would be
`vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2))`